# i keep getting a 403 forbidden permission error on my fedora server through my local network

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, http, http-status-code-403

Trying to view a javascript file (via http) on my server I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /jquery-1.8.2.js on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Fedora) Server at 192.168.1.3 Port 80
```

I have given all users access to the file like this:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/jquery-1.8.2.js
```

I have even gone as far as changing the user & group properties in the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Does the uid under which httpd is running have read and execute permission for the containing directory? Is /var/www/html the correct path for your document root? Is it possible that your Apache configuration tells the server to look elsewhere?

Comment: How did you configure Apache?

Comment: if by uid you mean user then yes, the user has 777 permissions

my document root is /var/www/html

im not sure if apache configuration tells the server to look elswhere, but the file is in the root directory

Comment: my configuration has the default root directory of /var/www/html/ all i did was change the config from
user apache 
group apache 

to

user user 
group user 

note: user is a user on my server

Comment: OK, now change it back.

Comment: OK, i just switched it back to user apache, group apache

Comment: I solved my problem, somehow creating a new empty file, copying the contents from jquery-1.8.2.js into the new document. renaming the empty document with the same name as jquery file and deleting the jquery file worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the apache error log?

Unless changed, the general default on the apache configuration is to only allow access to the sub-directories htdocs (your document root) and cgi-bin.  Access to all other directories is inhibited for security reasons.  You'll have to add an additional permission block for this and any other directories you might need to access.

Comment: i have not checked the logs but i am only trying to access a javascript file in the document root directory. so its giving me a 403 forbidden permission error, theres something going on with the apache daemons user permissions i think